How do I leverage Shopify APIs to do catalogue pull and order push of the brands that I have partnered with?
I want to create an SDK that allows any kind of a platform (content / media / OTT) to be able to specify what kind of brands they want to show and allow them to showcase it on their website. For this, I want to work with shopify brands on the seller side. But, how do I connect to the stores of these Shopify stores, so that I can do a catalogue pull to get details of their SKUs, and also send the order details back to the seller.
Have tried manually asking for brand's SKUs in an excel sheet, and then converting that into JSON, but that is not scaleale.
